# Unable to run Python script from XAMPP PHP

Tags: php, python, xampp

I am trying to run a simple Python script from XAMPP PHP that will create a file. Here is my python code -

```
    #!/Python27/python
def main():
     f= open("test.txt","w+")

     for i in range(10):
         f.write("This is line %d\r\n" % (i+1))
     f.close()   
if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
```

On my httpd.conf, I have changed following lines -

```
    <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm index.py
</IfModule>

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py
```

I am trying to call this python script from my PHP page like this -

```
$my_command = escapeshellcmd('c:/xampp/htdocs/Range_Optimization/script/hello.py');
    $command_output = shell_exec($my_command);
    echo $my_command;
    echo $command_output;
```

It is just displaying the path of the python file i.e output of

> echo $my_command;

But python script not running actually. While trying to run same .py file from Command Prompt, it is working fine. What am I missing here.

Comment: As per the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php , the windows path containing special characters might be getting replaced.

Comment: I tried to rename folder "Range_Optimization" to "Range". Still its not working.

Comment: Append python before your command. eg. $my_command = escapeshellcmd('python c:/xampp/htdocs/Range_Optimization/script/hello.py');

Comment: I checked this. This was also not working. Then I move .py file to the same path of .PHP. Then it worked. I believe somehow I am doing some mistake on the PATH. Not very sure.